# How can i make app stay on top, but under fullscreen sites like youtube

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, topmost

I've made my app window TopMost. Everything is ok but when i'm, for example, playing fullscreen youtube video in Chrome, my app is still on top. Taskbar is on top also. In Edge everythink is ok - fullscreen video is TopMost, my app and taskbar are under that video.

What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

Window stack is not a single stack actually. There are various "exceptions" that can affect Z-order of windows chain and its rendering algorithm.

In the sake of efficiency, some apps (including browsers and browser plugins) can use so called "overlay buffers" instead of generic window context to render themselves as fast and smooth as possible. Given that, your app can NOT be topmost window all the time as overlay buffers are exclusive regions that are fulfilled by respective owner application.